# mlflow not logging version of torchvision package

Tags: mlflow, torchvision, mlops

I suspect it is a limitation of mlflow not fully supporting plain pytorch (**not torchlightning**), but maybe someone knows a workaround that can be used on a large scale. When I run the experiment, code and artifacts are logged correctly, but in the `conda.yaml` torchvision is completely missed.

The conda.yaml file contains most critical dependencies:

```
channels:
- conda-forge
dependencies:
- python=3.9.18
- pip<=23.3
- pip:
  - mlflow==2.7.1
  - cloudpickle==2.2.1
  - numpy==1.26.0
  - packaging==23.2
  - pandas==2.1.1
  - pyyaml==6.0.1
  - torch==1.13.0
  - tqdm==4.66.1
name: mlflow-env
```

I tried constructing the environment in conda and after manually adding the correct version of torchvision I can run the experiment on this environment.

reduced pseudocode:

```
import 
import mlflow.pytorch
import logging
logging.getLogger("mlflow").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(<server URI>)
mlflow.set_experiment(<exp_name>)

def train(args):
    for epoch in epochs:
        # put metrics in metrics dictionary
        mlflow.log_metrics(metrics, epoch)


with mlflow.start_run():
    log_scalar("lr", learning_rate)
    log_scalar("epochs", epochs)
    mlflow.log_param("optimiser", f"{optimizer_ft}")
    mlflow.log_param("learning_rate", learning_rate)

    train(args)

    mlflow.pytorch.log_model(model_ft
                    , artifact_path="pytorch_model"
                    , pickle_module=pickle
                    , code_paths=[<source_files>])
```